# .NET Core SignalR "Channel" Purpose?

Tags: c#, angular, .net-core, signalr

I am using SignalR 1.1 in .NET Core, with a [strongly typed hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2#strongly-typed-hubs). E.g.

```
await _hub.Clients.All.FooBar(someData);
```

Then the Angular front end picks up that message here:

```
this.hubConnection.on('fooBar', (data) => {
  console.log('data');
});
```

I am transitioning this code from a legacy SignalR system (we switched from .NET to .NET Core). I keep encountering the idea of "channels", but I can't find anything in the documentation. When I google "SignalR channel", I get nothing.

If a channel is an actual concept, what is it used for? Also, is there any danger/performance hit due to NOT using channels?

The old code looks something like this:

```
let channelName = `${Constants.GeneralChannel}${comp.eventId}${comp.deskId}`;
comp.channelService.sub(channelName).subscribe(
```

Is there some SignalR good practice that I am missing here? Or is "channelName" just a concept that our team came up with (can't ask them, they are all gone).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely referring to "groups". Back to basics of SignalR examples, the chat room. Everyone who joins might be in a group or channel called "lobby". Now when they join a chat room named "Room1" there may be a group/channel for that the user gets added to so they can then see the "chat" going on in that room.

I use groups to put users together and send messages to groups based on content that is tailored for those groups.

Hope that helps... google "signalr groups" and you find more detailed info.